# Database fails to open on server

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have created a folder that all users have full control over.  In this folder is my backend, while the frontend resides on the local hard drive.  I can open the database on my development computer, even over the network.  On all other computers, the system simply loads the access welcome screen, or access opens and closes automatically.

Can there be virus protection or a firewall blocking this?  I have enabled network connections, and allowed all vba projects, etc.

Can there be a reference issue?  If I have a reference for an Outlook library, and have compiled the file into accde format, would this prevent any error messages and simply cause the database to fail?  I can open the backend tables on all computers, it is just the frontend that will not open.

Any suggestions will be helpful.  I am not at the site, so I will take all suggestions and try them when I return.

Comment: are all computers on same domain and logged on users are AD users with group permission to backend folder?

Answer (score 0):

A few things come to mind:

- Have a look in the Windows Event Log.
- Another issue could be happening if the locations where the front-end is located has not been added to the list of Trusted Locations in MS Access.
- If you put the accdb front-end on the user's machine, can it be opened? Do you get any error?
- As you mentioned, there could be a reference issue. Try to remove the reference and convert your early-binding with late binding instead (use `CreateObject`).
- Add some sort of logging to your application and log as much as possible to a text file from the startup sequence of your application. This may let you know if there is some of your startup code that fails.